# time.sleep работает в 2 раза дольше указанного

Tags: python

Есть код, это бот для биржи. Цикл while и time.sleep в конце, так вот, я указал sleep 180 сек, а по факту он работает ровно в 2 раза больше!

```
while True:
del_order()#Удаляем все ордеры.
last_order = get_last_order_status()
if last_order['status'] == 'canceled':
    current_price = get_price_shib()#Получаем текущую цену для ордера на покупку.
    temp = buy_order_under_price(current_price)#Выставляем ордер на покупку -2% от текущей цены.
if last_order['status'] == 'filled':
    write_balance()#Записываем текущий баланс в базу.
    temp_spot_shib = get_spot_balance_shib()#Проверяем баланс.
    spot_shib = int(temp_spot_shib)#Конвертируем строку в целочисленное значение.
    price_order = last_order['price']
    temp = sell_order_price(spot_shib, price_order)#Выставляем ордер на продажу, но не дешевле цены закупки.
time.sleep(90)
```

Вот время когда создаются ордера:

```
create 00.11.54 - delete 00.14.54
create 00.17.55 - delete 00.20.55
```

Получается ордер висит 180 сек, после удаления проходит ещё 180 сек и он опять создаётся.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Ну используйте логи же. Для этого логи и нужны чтобы не ванговать. Очевидно же что он заходит на итерации в ветку if и потом безусловно ждет 90 секунд. Вот так и набегает

Comment: 1) Исправьте табуляции 2) У вас указано 90, а не 180 3) Поставьте логирование либо хоть просто печать после каждой операции, а также в начале цикла, перед `time.sleep` и сразу после него. Тогда будет понятнее, что же происходит и в каком порядке.